# symfony unit tests: add/modify form action

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

I have a form, without action (is submitted with javascript) and I'm trying to write a unit test for it, but it fails because "action" attribute is missing:

> InvalidArgumentException : Current URI must be an absolute URL ("").

There is a way to do add it in unit tests or modify the html content using the crawler?

```
<form id="form_search_page">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" value="" />
    <button type="submit" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
</form>


$client = $this->makeClient(true);
$url = $this->createRoute("page_index"));
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$response = $client->getResponse();

$form = $crawler->filter('#form_search_page')->form();
$params = array(
    "form[text]" => "dummy title"
);
$form->setValues($params);
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('.pages li')->count());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$crawler
    ->filter('form#form_search_page')
    ->reduce(function (Crawler $form) use ($router) {
        $url = $router->generate('search_page', array(), true);

        $node = $form->getNode(0);
        if (!$node->hasAttribute('action')){
            $node->setAttribute('action', $url);
            $node->setAttribute('method', 'POST');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could test a ajax POST form submit as example above (Assuming a form with a CSRF token):

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url);

// retrieves the form token
$token = $crawler->filter('[name="myform[_token]"]')->attr("value");

$posturl = $this->client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate("the-url-of-the-submit");
// makes the POST request
$crawler = $this->client->request('POST', $posturl, array(
    'myform' => array(
        '_token' => $token
    )),
    array(),
    array(
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    )
);

$this->assertTrue(
    $this->client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
        'Content-Type',
        'application/json'
    )
);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank your for your feedback, I fixed it following my first idea, manipulate html using the crawler

Comment: Hi @CristianBujoreanu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) and/or upvote by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way:

```php
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/contacts');

        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit');

        // Select the form that contains this button
        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();

        // Modify the attribute action
        $form->getNode(0)->setAttribute('action', 'new-action-url');

        ...
```