# Symfony Unit Testing - Set Value for Javascript Rendered Elements

Tags: symfony, phpunit

In Unit Testing, How can I set a value to the Select box options in which drop down options are rendered from Javascript ?

When I set a value, I am getting Invalidargument exception.

**Note: Form is a general HTML Form**

Referred links: [symfony unit tests: add/modify form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027417/symfony-unit-tests-add-modify-form-action)

Comment: Have you tried to directly post the form without take it and populate?

Comment: @Matteo, I just checked that.. How can i get the form submitted values after posting ?

Comment: Hi! Good catch! Mark your answer as accepted so you can close the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @ Matteo comments.

In Unit testing,

For setting values for the Select box, which are not available in the Drop down,
Use Posting the data instead of submitting the form,

> $this->client->request('POST', $postUrl, $formValueArray);
>
> $formValueArray = array('data' => 'value');

or

```
$formValueArray = array( 
                'myform' => array(
                    'data' => 'value'
                ))
            );
```

Note: It can be used to set all the form fields which are not available in the forms.